# How could I run shell commands in Sublime Console?

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there any way to run shell commands in Sublime Console just like running Python codes in Sublime Console?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [Glue plugin](http://gluedocs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Otherwise you could use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) from python standard library, like so:

```py
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output(['python', '--version'])
```